# how to set the focus on a hidden textbox after it's shown using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i'm creating a website using bootstrap 3.3.6. on this website i have a login form which is revealed once the user clicks on the login-button above it (this part is already working).

now i'd like to achieve that once the user clicks on the button on the top and the login-form is shown, the focus will be set to the input field for the username.

it seems to be an issue to set the focus on an input field that is initially hidden, so i'm looking for a way to do it after it's been shown, even though i don't know how i could intercept bootstrap's javascript.

what i already tried to do is something like:

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
    var sender = this.id;

    if(sender == "btnLogin")
    {
        $("#loginEmail").focus();
    }
});
```

but it didn't work because of the problem with the visibility i mentioned above.

[image]

**Edit 20.1.2017, 12:38 - added HTML code as requested**

```
    <div class="user_login_content">
    <!--### Begin Header -> Navigation Top Right -> Login -> Login Form ###-->
    <div id="divLogin"
         data-bind="visible:!isAuthenticated()"
         data-default-submit-control-id="btnLogin" 
         style="display:none;">

        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="loginEmail" 
       name="loginEmail" 
       data-bind="value:email" 
       type="text" 
       class="form-control" 
       placeholder="Username or Email" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="loginPassword" 
       name="loginPassword" 
       data-bind="value:password" 
       type="password" 
       class="form-control" 
       placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input data-bind="value:saveLogin" id="chbSaveLogin" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="chbSaveLogin"><span></span>Remember me</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button id="btnLogin" data-bind="click:loginClick" type="button" class="button_ti">
    Login
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" data-bind="visible:loginErrorMessage" style="display: none">
            <p class="error" data-bind="text:loginErrorMessage"></p>
        </div>

        <a href="NewAccountUrl"
           target="_blank"
           title="New Account">
            New Account
        </a><br />

        <a id="hlForgotPassword">
            Forgot Password
        </a>
    </div>
    <!--### End Header -> Navigation Top Right -> Login -> Login Form ###-->
</div>
```

Comment: Is it satisfying the `if` condition at first instance? Also, are you showing up the `form` first and then trying to give focus.. Could you provide more detailed code if possible?

Comment: the if may no be satisfying, you're right, but it was just meant as experiment. what kind of further details about the code would you consider useful to help describing the problem?

Comment: Please provide us some html code in order to be able to give you an answer.

Comment: try e.target.id instead of this.id and check

Comment: All the code which we can try replicating to identify the issue..

Comment: _“i don't know how i could intercept bootstrap's javascript”_ –  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-events

Comment: @KD the problem is not that i don't receive the required value, but that the focus it ignored. both this.id and e.target.id would return me the correct value.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao done, i added the html as requested

Comment: So how do you show the login form using bootstrap? It is not clear from the html code you have posted.

Comment: @andreivictor showing as hiding is handled simply by applying bootstrap's css class "dropdown-toggle" to the desired element

Comment: @CBroe as your link mentions, All dropdown events are fired at the .dropdown-menu's ***parent*** element.

this way i can intercept the event as i would like to, but then inside of the method i'm not able to obtain the id of the button that has been clicked

$('.user_login').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function (e) {

    var sender = e.target.id; //doesn't return the id of the button that has been clicked
    console.info(sender);
})

Comment: _“All dropdown events have a `relatedTarget` property, whose value is the toggling anchor element.”_

Comment: @CBroe basing on yor input i could make it working (see code below). would you like to add it as answer, so i can accept it and upvote you, or should i answer it myself?

$('.user_login').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function (e) {

    var sender = "#" + e.relatedTarget.id;

    if(sender == "#btnLogin")
    {
        $("#loginEmail").focus();
    }
});

Comment: Yeah, just go ahead and answer it yourself, that’s fine by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved using the following code:

```
$('.user_login').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function (e) {

    var sender = "#" + e.relatedTarget.id;

    if(sender == "#btnLogin")
    {
        $("#loginEmail").focus();
    }
});
```

quoting http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-events

> show.bs.dropdown is the event that  is fired when the dropdown has been made visible to the user
>
> All dropdown events have a relatedTarget property, whose value is the toggling anchor element.

Answer (score 0):

**Are you trying something like this**

```
<input type="button" value="click">
<input type="text" id="user" style="display:none">

$('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
    $('#user').show()
    $('#user').focus();
})
```

Comment: no, because the showing/hiding of the login-panel is already handled by bootstrap. so i don't have to write an own code to show/hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your button has id which you have mentioned in selector (`btnLogin`) and try following

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function (e) {
    var sender = $(this).attr("id"); OR e.target.id

    if(sender == "btnLogin")
    {
        $("#loginEmail").focus();
        // OR try setTimeout(function() { $("#loginEmail").focus(); }, 2000);

    }
});
```

Comment: your solution seems to work (it would be enough to set 1ms of delay instead of 2000), but i'd like to check if there's a more elegant and correct way to solve it using bootstrap's events described on http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-events

see comments of my question